# How to reset OpenGL program's uniform attribute value to default?

Tags: api, opengl, shader

Let's say I have an OpenGL program that has a uniform attribute "diffuseColor". I have set it as following:

```
GLint location = glGetUniformLocation(handle, "diffuseColor");
glUniform3f(location, 1, 0, 0);
```

Now I would like to return it to the default value, which is encoded in the shader code. I do not have access to the source code, but I can call OpenGL API functions on the compiled program. Is there a way to read default value and set it with `glUniform3f`? Or even better, is there a something like `glResetUniform3f(GLint loc)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uniform initializers are applied upon linking the program. The value can then be read using `glGetUniformfv`/`glGetUniformiv`. There is no way to read the initial value of the uniform after you changed the uniform value.

There is no way to reset a single uniform to its initial value, but relinking the program will reset all uniforms in it. Linking a program is a costly operation and should be avoided in between frames.

Comment: Cool. I can just store the value on CPU and use glUniformXY to set it back when needed. Thank you.